Trouble Running DigitalSystemsVM on VirtualBox in Ubuntu
I am trying to install and run a virtual machine following this manual. However, I am getting the following error:
Error message: A critical error has occurred while running the virtual machine and the machine execution has been stopped.
The primary issue seems to be:
"Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack (Version: 7.0.18 r162988; VRDE Module: VBoxVRDP unusable because of 'VBoxExtPackVMRegister returned VERR_VERSION_MISMATCH, pReg=0000000000000000 ErrInfo='Helper version mismatch - expected 0x50000 got 0x30000'')"
I have added screenshots of the relevant parts of the log:
System Information
ERR MSG: VERR_VERSION_MISMATCH
